# Redirection only happening in FF, Safari

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, firefox, vagrant, http-redirect

It is a bit weird what I've been experiencing on a project I cloned from github.

I setup my vagrant then access the local IP address I specified for it :

> http://4.4.4.16

On chrome => I'm getting 200 and the front page is displayed

On Safari and Firefox => I'm getting 320 and instantly redirected to scripts page on the web.

I investigated a bit and found a the following redirection implemented on the .htaccess

> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website-of-script.com/ [L]

I removed it and then everything went back to normal, FF and Safari displays now the page on local dev.

But I still don't understand why would Chrome jumps the redirection although it's basically clear to redirect all localhost while Safari and Firefox don't.

Comment: Clear your cache in Chrome. Chrome tends to hangon to that. And then see how it works.

Comment: I've cleared the cache, restarted the vagrant, restarted my mac... But it's still the same, Chrome is not redirected.